# Module to suggest node revision to node author

Tags: nodes

Is there a module which facilitates functionality of allowing users to suggest node revision to author and author finally can publish the revised suggestion. Till the author is not accepting or rejecting the revision the existing node will be displayed.

Comment: There used to be [revision moderation](https://drupal.org/project/revision_moderation) but it was never stable. I think you may need to code it yourself

Comment: Also, check out [this list](https://groups.drupal.org/node/71618).

Comment: thanks Molot I was looking for this list, revision moderation module module page says what I need, but it needs to be ported to D7, I will see if I can do that.Thanks for the list again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [revisioning](https://drupal.org/project/revisioning). It seems more like it's set up for moderators to view revisions before approving content, but perhaps it can be used for what you need.

Comment: yeah I tried this module, issue is configuration it allows are on basis of user role instead of users and authors and also the point you have mentioned. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: have you checked out this issue for revision moderation? https://drupal.org/node/995876 there were patches to attempt to port it to D7. could point you in the right direction.

Comment: I didn't check this before, seems to be of great help, also I got hint to use workbench moderation from one of the comment.

Comment: I misconfigured this module, otherwise this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

After trying some modules in the list of modules Molot suggested and links robotsguide suggested I found [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module to give closest to the required functionality.